# pass pc's time to an html form

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to get pc's time with javascript and pass it into an html form. This is my code:

this is my javascript:

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()+":" + today.getSeconds();
document.getElementById('date').value = today;
</script>
```

and this is my html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="next_apply.php">                                                                        
  <input id="date" name="date">                                                                                                                                                                 
</form>
```

when I running the above code in jsfiddle seems to work. When I run it my pc (using XAMP) it is not working. Any idea what the problem might be here? 
This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deLkZ/1/

Comment: Define *not working*.  Does it do anything? Does your console show a javascript error? Does your input show? Give your input a type: `<input id="date" name="data" type="text">`  - the problem is almost certainly that the script needs to either be moved to the bottom of the page, or else put in a `document ready` function.

Comment: did it, but still nothing

Comment: Is this a follow up from what you asked about before?  And, btw, cale_b is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your script is at the bottom of the page, the input does not exist yet when your script runs.

So, either move your javascript block to just before the closing `</body>` tag, or else put it in a document ready:

```
window.onload = function () {
   var today = new Date();
   var dd = today.getDate();
   var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
   var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
   today = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes()+":" + today.getSeconds();
   document.getElementById('date').value = today;
}
```

Comment: thanks...works finally...you saved 2 days of work :-) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your script is backwards:

```
    <form method="POST" action="next_apply.php">                                                                        
      <input id="date" name="date">                                                                                                                                                                 
    </form>
           <script>
                var today = new Date();
                var dd = today.getDate();
                var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
                var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                today = mm +"/" + dd + "/" + yyyy + " " + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                document.getElementById('date').value = today;
</script>
```

Also, you forgot to add the date to your "today" string.  This fixes it.